# Java: Parsed XML but some things are missing

Tags: java, xml

Somehow the parsed XML file seems to be wrong or am I doing something wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<root>
    <quests>
       <quest id="test">
           <question>Just a little sentence.</question>
        </quest>
    </quests>
</root>
```

I parse it like that:

```
File file = new File("file.xml");

DocumentBuilderFactory dF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dF.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder dB = dF.newDocumentBuilder();

Document XML = dB.parse(file);

// ------------------------------------------
Element doc = XML.getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(doc.getChildNodes());

Element dx = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("quest").item(0);
System.out.println(dx.getAttribute("id"));
System.out.println(dx.getAttribute("id").length());
System.out.println(dx.getAttributes().getLength());
```

And this is what I get:

```
[root: null]

0
0
```

How could that be? How could I parse attributes of elements/tags/nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new XML file and with that it works!
I think the problem was maybe an hidden character inside the id
which causes the error...

Answer (score 3):

Weird I just copy-pasted your code and this is what I got for output

```
[root: null]
test
4
1
```

All that I can see wrong is that you should be doing `doc.getTagName()` but that is just minor...

`java version "1.6.0_21"`

Comment: `doc.getTagName()` returns `quest` and I have `java version "1.6.0_12"`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a getNodeValue() or getTextContent() missing, to get the actual attribute string.

Comment: `getNodeValue()` returns `null` and `getTextContent()` returns whitespace with `Just a little sentence.` inside it...

Comment: Have you tried outputting all attributes by using getAttributes()? But tbh I'm totally in the dark there, because your example should run.